# Trying to check if values exists in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to check if the players name and the invited players name that already exists in the database, I try this:

```
 public boolean isFriends(ProxiedPlayer inviter, ProxiedPlayer invited) {
    try {
        Statement sql = mySql.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE `friendinviter`='" + inviter.getName() + "'`invitedfriend`='" + invited + "';");
        ProxyServer.getInstance().broadcast("1");
        if(resultSet.next()) {
            sql.close();
            resultSet.close();
            return true;
        }
        sql.close();
        resultSet.close();
        return false;
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried debugging it by trying to get what it returns in the result-set but the code never came so far.

Comment: Your SQL syntax is incorrect. Check that the SQL statement is valid. Also, you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating strings to create an SQL statement.

Comment: Also it looks to me like you refer another user by name (inviter.getName) in your table - it depends on your use case, but generally you want to refer other entities by IDs and not by name

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in:

```
   ResultSet resultSet = sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE `friendinviter`='" + inviter.getName() + "' and `invitedfriend`='" + invited + "';");
```

You miss the logical operator in your where clues.

You should learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is you should use `PreparedStatement` for this portion of code.

Secondly in the line `"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friendinviter='" + inviter.getName() + "'invitedfriend='" + invited + "';"` the portion `"'invitedfriend='" + invited`  I think requires a VARCHAR to be passed as parameters but you are passing an instance of `ProxiedPlayer`. So the corrected code should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE ` friendinviter`='" + inviter.getName() + "'`invitedfriend`='" + invited.getName() + "';"
```